# Using Concert Technology application or Callable Library application with CVXPY

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, initialization, cplex, cvxpy

I am looking at a two step approach for a optimization problem. My first step is using a MILP formulation of the problem and the second step involves using the solution from the first step as an initial solution but now with a MIQP formulation. I have been able to apply this concept in MATLAB using CPLEX. However, I am now trying the same using CVXPY with CPLEX as the solver. Now I know about the warm_start option but this does not work with the CPLEX solver. I am able to set CPLEX parameters but I am not sure how to initialize my solution. I am thinking of setting the ADVANCE START SWITCH parameter for CPLEX to 1, but now I need to set the initial solution.  According to this page: http://www-eio.upc.es/lceio/manuals/cplex-11/html/usrcplex/solveMIP17.html, I need to use the method setVectors in a Concert Technology application, or by using CPXcopymipstart in a Callable Library application to set the initial solution. I am unsure of how to use this along with CVXPY.

Comment: In the CVXPY documentation I could not find a way to set a CPLEX MIP start (that is the feature that would be required). However, there is a related question here that provides a workaround in one of its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314581/initial-guess-warm-start-in-cvxpy-give-a-hint-of-the-solution Could you try setting the `value` property of variables and see whether this helps?

Comment: Tried this but it does not work

Comment: This question is closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484764.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for does not currently exist in CVXPY. CVXPY is a generic modeling layer that wraps around several solvers and it does not expose the CPLEX-specific [CPXreadcopymipstarts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/readcopymipstarts.html) nor [CPXaddmipstarts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/mipapi/addmipstarts.html) functionality.

The fact that setting the `value` property of variables and using the `warm_start` option, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314581) answer, doesn't work, is a CVXPY issue. It looks like there is an open github issue for this [here](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/issues/849). In the future, this will likely be the intended solution to your general question.

For now, you'll have to use one of the CPLEX APIs directly. As you mentioned in the comments of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484764) related stackoverflow question, you do not like the idea of using the lower-level CPLEX Python API. That leaves you with [docplex](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/index.html) as a viable option.